How to serialize a struct containing ‘URL.BookmarkCreationOptions’ into Data
I’m trying to encode/ decode a security scoped bookmark URL and store it in @AppStorage or UserDefaults. I got stuck with the ‘URL.BookmarkCreationOptions’ variable.
I read about JSONEndoder and PropertyListEncoder but I’m only able to encode basic types like String or Int using them.
All the samples I found are creating a struct containing the security scoped URL, but non is saving the struct for later use, which is, to my understanding, the basic idea of creating a bookmark.

You should store the bookmark itself, using the Data returned by bookmarkData. There is no need to encode anything. Why are you trying to encode the creation options?

You’re right. Looks like I got confused by the other code samples. Your comment got me into the right direction. Thanks.
